# A problem about set theory in Brezis Functional Analysis (Lemma 3.1's remark 1)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Here we have a family $(U_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$. Let $\Phi$ become a family of all $\cap_{\lambda \in \Gamma} U_{\lambda}$, where $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$ is  finite. Then, in Lemma $3.1$, we proved the family $\mathcal{F}$ obtained by forming arbitrary unions of elements from $\Phi$ is stable under $\cap_{finite}$ and $\cup_{arbitrary}$.

And the problem is, in the Remark $1$ below. If we reverse the order of operations in the construction of $\mathcal{F}$, that is, let $\Psi$ become a family of all $\cup_{\lambda \in \Gamma} U_{\lambda}$, where $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$ is arbitrary. Then $\mathcal{G}$ is obtained by forming finite intersections of elements from $\Psi$.

"The family $\mathcal{G}$ is not stable under $\cup_{arbitrary}$."

I was trying to construct a counterexample to prove it but failed. Any hints will be appreciated. Thank you in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Hint: consider subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which are either finite or are equal to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I found the ans by a related link nearby.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139307/set-operations-in-the-constructions-of-the-weak-topology-cannot-be-reversed?rq=1*emphasized text*